# How to query Active Directory for a user whose name contains a dollar sign ($)?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a code snippet that searches for a locally-defined Windows user :

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)) {
    using (Principal queryFilter = new UserPrincipal(context) { Name = accountName }) {
        using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(queryFilter)) {
            var principal = searcher.FindOne();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine if `accountName` contains normal alphanumerics, (eg "testuser"). However, if the name contains a dollar sign (eg "test$user"), `FindOne()` returns nothing.

I suspect the $ is being interpreted as some kind of metacharacter. Is there a way of preventing this from happening, so that it is interpreted literally?

Comment: Have you tried Unicode? U+0024, I don't have the notation ready, sorry.

Comment: @marc_s : Why yes it does! Never thought of that ... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking for a single entry - try this:

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "test$user");
```

Maybe that works?

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it solves my problem, although it doesn't actually answer my question ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an example of a leaking abstraction.  You can't do LDAP searches on the WinNT provider, which is what the Machine ContextType is using.